# Metadescription in Blogdown

Tags: html, r, blogdown

With a website created in blogdow it seems not possible to add metadescriptions permanently.

I tried to create metadescritions in `public/index.html`, and it works.
But, when I create for example a new post and then push it, my code for metadescription disappears. The same is true for the favicon and the title.

See my code below.

```html
<meta name="description" content="This is my content...">
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/my-favicon.ico">
<link href="/index.xml" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="This is my title" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fonts.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" media="all">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/ap-favicon.ico">
```

The above code has to remain permanently inside the public/index.html file, and should not be canceled when I create and push a new post.

Comment: You should learn more about how hugo works. The public/ folder is the compiled output of hugo. Instead, you should add your code into some template html files. Please read more at https://gohugo.io/templates/

Comment: Thanks fot the tip. I have not a index.html in the template files (lithimum theme).

Comment: I can create an index.html inside the template folder.But I have also other index.html related to public/mymenu1/index.html. How can I deal with these?

Comment: Hopefully, my answer below will help you to figure this out. Happy blogging with blogdown!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the template lookup order for home page](https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/#examples-layout-lookup-for-home-page), You'll see that for the lithimum theme, `layouts/_default/list.html` is used as the template for the home page.

The meta info is actually recorded at `./themes/hugo-lithium/layouts/partials/head.html` for the lithimum theme. [here](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium/blob/master/layouts/partials/head.html#L21-L34):

```
{{ if eq .RelPermalink "/" }}
<meta property="description" content="{{ .Site.Params.description }}">
{{ else }}
  {{ if .Description }}
  <meta property="description" content="{{ .Description }}">
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}

{{ if .Keywords }}
<meta property="keywords" content ="{{ delimit .Keywords ", " }}">
{{ end }}

{{ with .OutputFormats.Get "RSS" }}
<link href="{{ .RelPermalink }}" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="{{ $.Site.Title }}" />
{{ end }}
{{ partial "head_highlightjs" . }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/fonts.css" | relURL }}" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/main.css" | relURL }}" media="all">
```

According to the source code, you only need to set the parameters for description, favicon and keywords in your config file (`config.toml`) or in the yaml header of your post.

To further customize the header, you can create your own `./layouts/partials/head.html` to override the template.